# Filling a 2D matrix in numpy using a for loop

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm a Matlab user trying to switch to Python.

Using Numpy, how do I fill in a matrix inside a `for` loop?

For example, the matrix has 2 columns, and each iteration of the `for` loop adds a new row of data.

In Matlab, this would be:

```
n = 100;
matrix = nan(n,2); % Pre-allocate matrix
for i = 1:n
    matrix(i,:) = [3*i, i^2];
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you have to install numpy using

```
$ pip install numpy
```

Then the following should work

```
import numpy as np    
n = 100
matrix = np.zeros((n,2)) # Pre-allocate matrix
for i in range(1,n):
    matrix[i,:] = [3*i, i**2]
```

A faster alternative:

```
col1 = np.arange(3,3*n,3)
col2 = np.arange(1,n)
matrix = np.hstack((col1.reshape(n-1,1), col2.reshape(n-1,1)))
```

Even faster, as Divakar suggested

```
I = np.arange(n)
matrix = np.column_stack((3*I, I**2))
```

Comment: Or `I = np.arange(n)` and then `np.column_stack((3*I, I**2))`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that these are not matrices, despite the variable name.  They are arrays.  Arrays are used in the same way matrices are, but work differently in a number of ways, such as supporting less than two dimensions and using element-by-element operations by default.  Numpy provides a matrix class, but you shouldn't use it because most other tools expect a numpy array.

Answer (score 4):

This is very pythonic form to produce a list, which you can easily swap e.g. for np.array, set, generator etc.

```
n = 10

[[i*3, i**2] for i, i in zip(range(0,n), range(0,n))]
```

If you want to add another column it's no problem. Simply

```
[[i*3, i**2, i**(0.5)] for i, i in zip(range(0,n), range(0,n))]
```